# Navigate to certain fragment from another dynamic module

Tags: android, android-navigation, multi-module

Is there any way to navigate to a certain fragment from another dynamic module and not navigate to the start destination? If not, what are the alternatives?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.example.feature.login.presentation.LoginFragment"
    android:label="LoginFragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/actionLoginToHome"
        app:destination="@id/featureHomeNavGraph" />

</fragment>

<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/featureHomeNavGraph"
    app:graphResName="feature_home_nav_graph"
    app:moduleName="feature_home" />
```

While this code works fine, it navigates me to the start destination but I need to navigate to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Navigate to specific fragment and do not use `<include-dynamic>`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.example.feature.profiles.presentation.details.ProfileDetailsFragment"
    android:label="Profile Details"
    app:moduleName="feature_profiles" />
```

**Solution 2:** Create a new graph XML with different start destination.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this for embedded nav graphs is to have a blank Navigation Fragment.  You get your action to go to this fragment and then send it arguments on where to navigate next.  Some sample code:

```
class NavigatorFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_PAGE_NAME = "REQUEST_PAGE_NAME"

        const val PAGE_TYPE_ACTIVATE_CARD = "PAGE_TYPE_ACTIVATE_CARD"
        const val PAGE_TYPE_CREDIT_LIMIT = "PAGE_TYPE_CREDIT_LIMIT"
        const val PAGE_TYPE_SCC_HUB = "PAGE_TYPE_SCC_HUB"
        const val PAGE_TYPE_ABOUT_CARD = "about_card"
        const val PAGE_TYPE_MAKE_PAYMENT = "PAGE_TYPE_MAKE_PAYMENT"

        fun createBundle(pageName: String) =
            Bundle().apply {
                putString(REQUEST_PAGE_NAME, pageName)
            }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        when (arguments?.getString(REQUEST_PAGE_NAME)) {
            PAGE_TYPE_ACTIVATE_CARD -> 
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.to_activateSecuredCard)
        PAGE_TYPE_CREDIT_LIMIT -> 
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.to_creditLimit)
        PAGE_TYPE_ABOUT_CARD -> 
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.to_aboutSecuredCard, arguments)
        PAGE_TYPE_SCC_HUB -> 
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.to_sccHub)
        PAGE_TYPE_MAKE_PAYMENT -> 
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.to_sccMakePayment)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding: FragmentSecuredCardNavigatorBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_secured_card_navigator, container, false)

    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner


    if (findNavController()
                 .currentDestination.toString()
                 .contains(this.javaClass.name)
        ){
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

main navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@+id/home_dashboard_fragment">

<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_secured_card" />
<!-- rest of navigation graph-->
.....
</navigation>
```

secured card navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_root_secured_card"
app:startDestination="@id/securedCardNavigator">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/securedCardNavigator"
    android:name="com.greendotcorp.securedcard.fragment.NavigatorFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/to_activateSecuredCard"
        app:destination="@+id/activateSecuredCard"

        app:popUpTo="@+id/securedCardNavigator"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>
</navigation>
```

Navigating to secured card navigation:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_root_secured_card, NavigatorFragment.createBundle(NavigatorFragment.PAGE_TYPE_SCC_HUB))
```